# Выборка в Laravel

Tags: laravel

Доброго дня. В контроллер для выборки передаю $_POST['rid']. Дело в том, что в ответ может придти либо ссылка на один аудио файл, либо ссылки на 20 фото файлов, в зависимости от $_POST['rid']:

```
$record = \Models\Loading::select('filename')->where('rid', $_POST['rid'])->get()->toArray();
        foreach($record as $file){
            $arr = array('filename' => $file["filename"]);
        }
        echo json_encode($arr);
```

Отправкой rid и обработкой ответов занимается Javascript:

```
$.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: "http://portal.com/show/file/",
                data: {'rid' : rid
                },
                dataType: "json",
                success: function(data) {
                    data = JSON.parse(data);
                    console.log('ОТВЕТ: ', data);

                    document.body.innerHTML = ('<audio src="{{ base_url() }}/public/' + data.filename + '" autoplay controls preload="auto" style="margin: auto 0;" target="_blank"></audio>');

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                console.log("ERROR: " + textStatus + ", " + errorThrown);
                console.log(jqXHR);
            }
        });
```

Когда возвращается ссылка на один аудио файл, он корректно открывается в новом окне и проигрывается. А вот, когда жду 20 ссылок, в ответ возвращается только ссылка на первый файл и все. Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 foreach($record as $file){
        $arr[] = array('filename' => $file["filename"]);
    }
```

Comment: Ссылки на фото стали приходить корректно, а ссылка на аудио не приходит.

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов Тебе всегда будет приходить массив. Смотри аудио в `data[0]['filename']`

Comment: Просто не пойму, куда ссылка на аудио могла деться?))

Comment: Посмотри в консоле. Ты же выводишь там свой респонс

Comment: Спасибо. Разобрался)